# ProFTPD: Limit user to one directory only, and link that user directory to a specific folder

Tags: linux, ftp, proftpd

This question has two parts, sorry if it's a bit simple but I'm struggling with it.

Firstly, I've set up user accounts, which log in fine to the FTP server. However, within the FTP client I can view every single folder above the default user folder. How do I stop this from happening so that the user can't go up the directory tree and in to every folder held on the server.

Secondly, I want the default folder which the user is given to not be in the User folder (if that makes sense). I want to be able to have direct access to the www/html folder as this is where me and my friend will be uploading our project to. So when I log in, I want to be taken to the html folder instead of my user area.

Is this the correct way to do it? Or is there a way where whatever I put in to my user folder will be copied directly to the html folder?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [DefaultRoot](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Chroot.html) configuration directive